# Local Storage data retrieval

Tags: local-storage, sencha-touch-2

I am creating a form where i am saving the data into the local storage. I am calling the proxy in the model. But i am not sure of is how to get the data from the local storage.

My code is:

```
var model = new InfoImage.model.configure.configModel();
model.data.servname = servname;
                        model.data.port = port;
                        model.data.protocol = protocol;
                        model.data.username = username;
                        model.data.password = password;
                        model.data.domain = domain;
                        model.data.apptitle = apptitle;
                        model.data.appconfig = appconfig;
                        model.save();

                        //Ext.getStore('configStore').load();
                        users = Ext.getStore('configStore').sync();
                        var item = localStorage.getItem('servname');
```

my model is:

//Defining a data structure for the Work Item List

```
Ext.define('InfoImage.model.configure.configModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',

    config : {
        //Defining the fields required in the Work Item List
        fields : [ 'servname', 'port', 'protocol', 'username', 'password',
                'domain', 'appconfig', 'apptitle', 
                'appconfig' ],


        proxy : {
            type : 'localstorage',
            id : 'configId'
        }
    }
});
```

`var item = localStorage.getItem('servname');` is giving me **"null"** result. I have a store defined but i haven't used it yet. Any idea how I should go about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store is called 'Items' and if it's loaded, you can to these :

```
var store = Ext.getStore('Items'); // Get the store
store.add({...}); // Add an instance of you model item
store.sync(); // Will add the item to the locastorage
var item = store.getAt(0) // Get the first item in the store
store.remove(item); // Remove the selected item from the store
store.sync(); // Will remove the item from the localstorage
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Please visit: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage

If you want to save data in local storage you should call `yourStore.sync()`

If you want to add data to store (not to localstorage) you should call `yourStore.add( object )`

Then if you need to update your localstorage with new data you should call `yourStore.sync()` again.

If you want to fill your store with data from localstorage you should call `yourStore.load()`.

Comment: i dont want to add it in the store. I want to retrieve the value from the local storage. Is that possible?

Comment: First sync store data with localstorage: users = Ext.getStore('configStore').sync(); and then you can load it. If you didn't add any data (using sync) to localstorage you can't get anything from it, because it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
first you define model like below
Ext.define('LoginDemo.model.User',
{
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    config:
    {
        identifier: 'uuid',
        fields:['name','add','mail'],
        proxy:`enter code here`
            {
                type:'localstorage',
                id:'mylogin'
            }

    }
});
then put model into store using following code

listeners:
                        {

                            tap:function()
                            {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Hi');


                                var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', 
                                {
                                    model: 'LoginDemo.model.User'

                                });

                                //loads any existing data from localStorage
                                store.load();
                                //now add some Searches
                                store.add({name: 'Deepak',add: 'Mumbai',mail:'deepakg.borade@gmail.com'},
                                          {name: 'Rahul',add: 'Pune',mail:'deepakg13.borade@gmail.com'});
                                //finally, save our Search data to localStorage
                                store.sync();
                                                                //fetch data locationwise
                                var a=store.getAt(0);
                                console.log(a);
                            }
                        }
```